# "cannot find symbol" while trying to get an object from an arrayList in a map

Tags: java

I am trying to modify an ArrayList in a map, but it keeps giving me the "Symbol not found error"

Here is the code:

```
Map inventories = new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Item>>();
inventories.put("itms_eqped", new ArrayList<Item>(6));
System.out.println(inventories.get("itms_eqped").get(0));
```

Here is the error

```
./Main.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println(inventories.get("itms_eqped").get(0));
                                                ^
symbol:   method get(int)
location: class Object
```

I've also tried adding stuff to the arrayList and I'm getting the same error: "Cannot find symbol".

Comment: You are using a **raw** `Map`. Don't do that. `Map<String, ArrayList<Item>> inventories = new TreeMap<>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare type of your key and value for Java to know which type it should use. Otherwise, java will consider your key and value as type Object.

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Item>> inventories = new TreeMap<>();
```